# Accessing an Access database on a network share

Tags: asp.net, database, asp.net-mvc-4, ms-access, shared-directory

I am having a problems connecting to an Access database hosted on a network share. 
My problem is when attempting to read a database on a network share from a different server I get the following error:

> The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file. It is already
>   opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its
>   data.

My Connection string in web.config:

```
<add name="DbKoneksiAbsensiHO" providerName="System.Data.OleDb" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\\192.168.100.114\dbhris\absentdb.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=bla123;User ID=admin"  />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put this code to my web.config 

And It's Solve my Problem

But I need to set folder and file permission when shared folder to network.

Answer (score 0):

i received the same error a while ago where the problem was resolved by **opening the database** on server. After opening the database it shows a row which says "Read Only" just click the button and it will ask where you want to save the new database which is "Not Read Only".

Hope this helps

Comment: I can't save as database. because it's use for another application.
but thanks for your response.